# PHP forced download going to webpage

Tags: php, excel, download, html, xls

I have an issue with the force download of a file.

I'm using PHPExcel to create a xls file based on information extracted from our database. This all works fine and the Excel file works as required.

I then attempt to force download of created file using the following function. However it  downloads webpage rather than as a file.

Currently developing on Win XP SP3, Notepad++, XAMPP (Apache 2.4.3, PHP 5.4.7).

**function following

```
public function downloadfile($file){
    if(file_exists($file) && is_file($file)){           
        //ob_start();
        echo $file;
        echo "in file exists";
        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        ob_clean();
        flush();
        readfile($file);    
        //ob_end_flush();
    }else
        echo "file or location does not exist <br>";    
        echo $file;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

If its a excel file then just redirect to that url and by default it will ask for file download.

```
header("Location: http://site.com/path/to/file/filename.xlsx");
/* Make sure that code below does not get executed when we redirect. */
exit;
```

If in javascript give

```
location.href = 'http://site.com/path/to/file/filename.xlsx';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=UTF-8");
header("Content-Disposition: inline; filename=\"" . $fileName . ".xls\"");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
readfile($filePath);
```

try this